# Using WickedPDF with Webpacker & Bulma CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to use [WickedPDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) in a Rails 6 project that uses the [Bulma CSS](https://bulma.io/) framework. However, I cannot get it to work properly and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

I have a `pdf.html.slim` layout file with the following:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    title= content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : t('website.title')
    = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag 'pdf'
    = wicked_pdf_javascript_pack_tag 'pdf'

  body
    .containers
      .container
        = yield
```

My `app/javascript/packs/pdf.js` file looks like this:

```js
import 'stylesheets/pdf';
```

which in turn calls `app/javascript/stylesheets/pdf.scss`

```
@import 'colors';

// ~ to tell webpack that this is not a relative
// import (but in node_modules dir):
@import '~bulma';
```

When I open a PDF, however, none of the Bulma styling is applied.

I'm using a vanilla `config/webpacker.yml` file:

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .vue
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

The styling currently works as expected on the website but not on PDFs.

I can also confirm that if I use a link to the assets via a CDN, the PDF renders correctly.

I'd expect that using Bulma CSS via webpacker displays styles properly in wicked_pdf generated files.

#### System specifications

- OS: MacOS 10.15.5
- Rails version: 6.0.3.2
- wicked_pdf gem version: 2.1.0
- wkhtmltopdf version: 0.12.6

Comment: Under Rails 5.2 without Webpack I call my scss file like this `<%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("PDF.scss") %>` I basically encrypt it to Base 64 per wicked pdf helper. I commented out this line ; `<% # wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "PDF.scss" %>` then probably ended up with the same problem back then ..

Comment: Thanks for this. The wickedpdf docs clearly say that `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag` and `wicked_pdf_javascript_pack_tag` work. I had a look at the source and (in development) it appears to be no different from running `javascript_pack_tag` or `stylesheet_pack_tag`. Which leads me to believe that if the assets are fine in the browser, they should be compiling fine for the PDF generation...no clue why it doesn't work. If I can avoid running the base64 encrypter that would be best/more readable.

Comment: They clearly say base 64 is an option. And I didn't see anything being particularly slow... Also a guess would be the scss: Because it is basically run outside Rails, it may not be preprocessed. Try to convert your Scss to CSS and check if works.